# python 3 try-except all with error

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

Is it possible to do a try-except catch all that still shows the error without catching every possible exception? I have a case where exceptions will happen once a day every few days in a script running 24/7. I can't let the script die but they also don't matter since it retries regardless as long as I try except everything. So while I track down any last rare exceptions I want to log those to a file for future debugging.

example:

```
try:
    print(555)
except:
    print("type error: "+ str(the_error))
```

Any way to replace `the_error` with a stack trace or something similar?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Yes you can [catch all errors](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#Exception) like so:

```
try:
    print(555)
except Exception as e:
    print("type error: " + str(e))
```

For the stack trace I usually use the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module:

```
import traceback

try:
    print(555)
except Exception as e:
    print("type error: " + str(e))
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do:

```
   try:
       print(555)
   except Exception as err:
      print("Erro {}".format(err))
```

Or use `raise`

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) are always your friend

> Tip: Avoid use "except:"

Use something more descriptive like

```
...
except (ValueError, KeyError):
```

Unless your code is very well tested, you can't figure out every error.