# Is there anything fundamentally wrong with scheduling recurring tasks with indefinite while loop?

Tags: python, time, while-loop

I have an application I want to run on a virtual machine to update a database with data returned from an API every 15 minutes.

In researching the issue, it seems that the traditional approach is to use a scheduling library, etc (i.e. run task x every hour).

Is there anything inherently wrong with just using a recurring while loop and a time.sleep(900) delay? In other words, will it crash/ eat up too much ram/etc.. This program would run basically indefinitely on a virtual machine.

```
while True:
    print('hello world')
    time.sleep(900)
```

Comment: For recursion, the program will run eventually out of stack depth and/or accidentally keep objects alive if not somehow “springboarding” - which is exactly what timing libraries take care of.

Comment: What's the recursive part of your code? All you posted is sequential.

Comment: You have to [catch all exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103712/python-3-try-except-all-with-error), otherwise your script will die on the first error until you restart it. Using a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job would probably be easier.

Comment: I think OP means *recurring*, not recursive.

Comment: You're right-- I meant recurring. I also have an if statement before the loop starts that should catch all exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, refer to the [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). If it is readable, easy to understand and does the job *correctly* then you’re good.

Having said that have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491442/python-sleep-for-memory-consumption-measurement-not-accurate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874118/python-why-does-time-sleep-cause-memory-leak) to see similar questions on how time.sleep works. You may change your mind depending on how accurate you need the sleep cycle to be